# python2 how to handle file input as argument with subprocess.call

Tags: python-2.7

---

I need to use a file as argument to the command but subprocess.call returns following error

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as F:
...     subprocess.call(['cat', F])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
   errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

However when file is not stored as variable it works fine

```
>>> subprocess.call(['cat', 'test.txt'])
  fruit=banana
  fruit=mango
  fruit=apple
  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Code `with open('test.txt') as F` opens the file and assigns its pointor to variable `F`.

If I understand correctly you wanted file's content. Since `subprocess.call` required a command like you execute from terminal/console(In your case `cat test.txt`). Here in the `subprocess.call` you are passing `File Descriptor` sometime called `File Pointer` instead of file itself.

Therefore from the code if you really want a file content, you can simply use `F.read()` or `F.readlines()`. For Example

```
with open('test.txt') as F:
   print F.readlines()
```

Also note that `subprocess.call` expect arguments as `string`. In the first case its the file object i.e `<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7fa64a6f5a50>` that leads to a `traceback` whereas in the second case its string i.e `test.txt` that's why works without any issue.